# Como setar um valor em uma tag input de outro site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Como eu poderia fazer para conseguir passar um valor para um campo `<input>` de outro site?

Na prática, gostaria de que quando o usuário clicasse em um link, botão, etc. fosse aberta uma outra página de um site qualquer (Ex. www.google.com.br) e em determinado campo aparecesse um valor que tenho em meu site.

Assim seria necessário só que o usuário submetesse o formulário nesse outro site.

Utilizo as tecnologias PHP, JavaScript e JQuery.

Comment: Se o "outro site" não é da tua autoria, como vais manipular o seu comportamento para fazer chegar informação e aplicar a mesma onde pretendes? Num motor de busca como o Google, ainda se resolver, mas em outros sites... difícil.

Comment: Podes explicar quel é o outro site e se aceita CORS?

Answer (score 2):

Como foi dito, se o outro site não for seu, fica complicado, mas alguns sites disponibilizam isso de forma simples, pela url....

- https://www.google.com.br/search?q=valor
- https://br.search.yahoo.com/search?p=valor
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=valor
- http://codepen.io/search?q=valor
- https://github.com/search?q=valor

Answer (score 1):

Os campos de um form normalmente são pre-enchidos pelo atributo `value=""`. Simplesmente chamando um outro site, não há maneira de você modificar esse atributo para por qualquer dado.

***Às vezes***, como @MatheusCristian mencionou, o site é feito que pode passar algum valor pela URL, e aí *aquele* site coloca aquele valor dentro do atributo `value`.

Assim, está a mercê da implementação do outro site, e não tem nada garantido.

Answer (score 0):

da p/ rodar um script javascript para preencher o que você quiser, mas, porém, entretanto, o script irá rodar e preencherá somente o navegador onde o script rodar, ou seja, se quiser fazer isso para "obrigar" uma programação ao site não vai rolar, mas se quiser escrever uma "camada" de javascript após a pagina do navegador abrir dai sim é possível, basta abrir o console,colar o script e executa-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Poderás usar o método GET exemplo:

```
$x = $_GET['id'] ? $_GET['id'] : NULL;
```

e no html:

```
<input type="text" value="<?= $x ?>"/>
```

no site1 podes fazer para redirecionar para o site2 exemplo:

```
<?php header('Location: www.site2.com/index.php?id='. $id); ?>
```

e o valor de x será o valor de $id